# open excel file without creating new instance

Tags: excel, vb.net

i've looked up all topics regarding this and still can't find solution.
My main issue is that any time I'm opening excel file from my application it gets opened in new instance. What i want - detect if there's running excel, if there is - use this instance, if not - create new one.

This is not working:

```
Dim xlsApp As Object
Dim AllExcelProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")
If AllExcelProcess.Length = 0 Then xlsApp = New Excel.Application Else xlsApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

AllExcelProcess works correctly returning that there's running excel application, yet the GetObject always returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me from within Word and an excel instance already open. Microsoft 365.

```
Sub main()

On Error Resume Next
  Set excelapp = GetObject(class:="Excel.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear
  If excelapp Is Nothing Then Set excelapp = CreateObject(class:="Excel.Application")

  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "Excel could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

 On Error GoTo 0

excelapp.Workbooks("Book2").sheets("Sheet1").Range("j2").Value = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Just checked. xlsApp = GetObject(Class:="Excel.Application") - with opened  excel workbook returns nothing for me. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do what I wanted:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim xlsApp As Object = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If xlsApp Is Nothing Then xlsApp = New Excel.Application
```

I had 2 issues you might want to check out:

1. You have Microsoft Excel library loaded under References. If you can't find it, add existing EXCEL.EXE to it
2. If still not working, try GetObject on other objects, can VS detect their classes or not. In my case it was not working at all

Solution:
I added MS Excel library, created new solution. GetObject started working there, everything further was easy using above code.